# What variable points to Java Build Path->Default output folder in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

In the Eclipse Ant task configuration, I can use variables to point to different aspects of my project. Ex: `build_files`, `java_type_name`, etc..

Is there an existing variable that resolves the `Java Build Path->Default Output Folder` as configured in the Java Build Path window?  None of the default vars seem to point to that configuration, unless I am missing the obvious.

Comment: An Eclipse project may have multiple output folders. Besides, shouldn't your Ant script already know that location? Remember, you should always be able to run the Ant script directly (outside Eclipse).

Comment: @Andreas - I'm trying to override the Ant script definitions as I want it to generate files in a specific location to use by the Java builders.  Similar to maven's target/generated_sources folder.